# Why &i32 can compare with &&i32 in Rust?

Tags: rust

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn largest<T>(list: &[T]) -> &T
where
    T: PartialOrd + Display
{
    let mut largest = &list[0];
    for item in list.iter() {
        // item: &i32
        // largest: &i32
        // &largest: &&i32
        if item > &largest {
            println!("item > &largest: {}", item > &largest);
        }
        if item > largest {
            println!("item > largest: {}", item > largest);
            largest = &item;
        }
    }
    &largest
}

fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 45];
    let result = largest(&number_list);
    println!("The largest number is {}", result);
}
```

In the largest function, both `item > largest` and `item > &largest` can compile success

I have tried compare &i32 with &&i32 like above, it gave me an error: **no implementation for {integer} < &{integer} and {integer} > &{integer}**.

```
let a = 10; // i32
let b = &a; // &i32
let c = &b; // &&i32
println!("{}", b > c);
```

What i expected is `item > &largest` raise similar error like `b > c`.
Please tell me why `item > &largest` can compile successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#impl-PartialOrd%3C%26B%3E-for-%26A) of `PartialOrd` says that if `a.partial_cmp(b)` is available, then `(&a).partial_cmp(&b)` is also available (forwarding the call with `*` on both parameters).

In the `largest<T>()` function, we state that `T` implements `PartialOrd`, then `item > largest` is correct because the implementation for `&T` will forward the call to `(*item).partial_cmp(*largest)`.

In `item > &largest`, `item` plays the role of `self` and this parameter is special because the compiler adds automatically (by convenience) all the `&` at the call site in order to match the exact type of `self` in the function signature ([see the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#wheres-the---operator)).
Here the compiler will silently add a `&`, as if we had written `&item > &largest`, which will be forwarded (in the implementation for `&T`) to `item > largest` (and again to `*item > *largest`).
All of this is possible because the compiler knows that in the end `T` implements `PartialOrd`.

In your example with `a`, `b`, `c`, we don't know exactly the type of `a`; we assume that it could be deduced lately to `i32` by default, but until this late decision, nothing states that this type will implement `PartialOrd`.
The decision to add silently a `&` on the left side in order to ease the invocation cannot be made.
If we force the type of `a` with `10_i32`, this type is known early enough to implement `PartialOrd` then the compiler can help us by changing silently `b > c` into `&b > c`.

Comment: Could have sworn I did, but when I try it now it works.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, you saved me !! I'd been troubled for a long time